# MySQL -- Making it all one query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to see if I can accomplish the following situation in one query:

I have a table with multiple columns, however, only two are important: version and groupId.
Many rows can share the same groupId value, the version column is a number that needs 
to be sorted.

Given two groupId values, A and B, I would like to return two rows in the end.  I want to find the most recent version number for each group A and B.

Thanks for your help.  Sorry if this is fairly obvious, but I was having difficulty

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT groupId, MAX(version) max_version
FROM YourTable
WHERE groupId IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY groupId;
```

You didn't specify any data types so I assumed that `groupId` could actually take character values like `'A'`. Just change this to suit your needs. The basic idea is that you `GROUP BY` your `groupId` after filtering out only those values which interest you. Then you `SELECT` the `MAX(version)` for each of those values.

Comment: HA!, yes I think this will do it,  I won't be able to try till later on, but It seems so painfully obvious now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
  select p.id,p.groupid,p.version from tablename p
    left join 
    (
        select max(id) id1 from tablename
        group by groupId
        order by max(id) desc
    ) t on t.id1 = p.id
```

Assuming you have a primary key column id in table

Answer (score 0):

I assume version is an integer

```
SELECT MAX(version), `group` FROM table WHERE `group` IN (A, B) GROUP BY `group`
```